# MongoDB failed connect 10061

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb ( windows 32, `storageEngine=mmapv1`), it was working fine, I already created several DBs, inserted documents and collections. Surprisingly, when I was trying to connect today, it kept saying `connect failed`and emitting `errno:10061`I can't understand why. It's probably worth noting that last shutdown was unclean, so I tried `Mongod –dbpath data\db --repair` but nothing changed. Could you please help ?

Comment: Did you start the mongod server?, like on cmd typing `mongod.exe` ?

Comment: Yes I did, now to resolve the issue, I created an other folder called data0/db to replace data/db. It worked, so now mongodb is connected but all my DBs are now not accessible.

Comment: But you have the database files right?

Comment: https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/importing-json-records-into-mongodb-with-mongoimport/

Comment: Yes, I exported them last time. And the link is helpful. Many thanks Hackerman :)

Comment: Yeah...using mongoimport should be able to allow you to recover your databases...And no worry man, I am glad to help, I start learning mongodb about 3 years ago, and I started on Windows too(then I move out to Linux but that is another story)

Comment: @Hackerman how has your experience with mongodb been ? I have just picked up mongodb a few months back and wanted know

Comment: It's great, but, running MongoDB on Linux seems more natural. It's a growing ecosystem with a great community, always improving. Did you check the training available on mongodbuniversity?....Also check robomongo!